# Graphical Bug: how to debug?

Tags: graphics, bug-reporting, debugging

I have been experiencing a strange graphical bug which I'd like to report on Launchpad.

The bug occurs randomly when pressing mouse buttons in some applications, like for example when I resize tables in Libreoffice Writer or when I use autoscroll in Firefox. When a mouse button is pressed, a black screen is displayed or sometimes the login...The bug is transient: it disappears as soon as the mouse button is released!

I'm basically facing 3 problems before I can report it:

- I don't know how to reproduce it
- I don't know which package is faulty (hardware driver?xorg?unity?, etc)
- I don't know how to show evidence of it! A screenshot cannot capture it...

This is really annoying and I would really like to report this bug so it can be solved.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Launch the application from the command line. Look for error messages, try to reproduce the crash.

You can also use apport and/or apport-retrace

[image]

See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

Comment: perhaps you haven't read my post well. I do not know what application is causing the bug (probably an underlying process of the gnome graphical interface) and there is no crash whatsoever which would require the use of apport.

Comment: You said the crash occurs when running Libreoffice Writer. So first run Libreoffice Writer from the command line and look for errors. If there are none, run `apport-retrace` right after the crash. See the link I gave you for more information. Post back if that does not work.

Comment: I edited the description since it seemed to be confusing. I repeat that there is NO crash, the applications keep running but the display is interrupted by black screens whenever the mouse is pressed. I will try to record a video next time it happens. How do I know if it's the X server, unity, compiz or whatever else that is faulty?

Comment: Try working your way through the debugging X wiki - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Debugging